# Kile on Linux Mint: Built-in viewer has disappeared

Tags: kile, ide, live-preview

I am new to LaTeX, and I've decided to focus on Kile as my IDE. This, largely because it has features that will allow me to learn at a faster pace.

Unfortunately, the Kile manual ([link](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kile/kile/index.html) doesn't have screenshots and a walk-through to familiarize newbies to the toolbars and menus.

Confusingly, it ***is*** possible to use an external viewer (e.g., Okular), ***OR*** to view the compiled document in a Live Preview pane on the RHS of Kile's window.

I have seen the built-in viewer but, having once used Okular as the 'external' viewer, I cannot get the internal viewer's pane to re-materialize. This, despite 'Enabling Live Preview', choosing to run 'live preview' from the drop-down menu ("Build")...and setting automatic re-compilation 0.5 seconds after any changes to the document [see image below]
[image].

Any ideas of what's run amok here?

Also, if anyone can explain Kile's distinction between "build" and "compile", that would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a chance you just resized the editor window to completely cover it? If so, try dragging the right edge to the left.

Comment: From what I can tell from a quick glance, "QuickBuild" is something that runs multiple compilation tools at once; you can configure exactly what it does, however.

Comment: 'Build' is more general. Compiling is one kind of building, but there are others. Even viewing the PDF is classified as 'building'. So is converting it.

Answer (score 1):

Ah HAH !!-----
I discovered today what happened to the Kile preview window: under the Settings drop-down menu, choose Configure Kile. There, you will see a tick-box to choose to open the Document Viewer (preview pane) as a separate window. I must've absent-mindedly toggled this while hacking away at Kile's GUI.
[image]

Comment: Still ... 'show in external window' shouldn't really mean 'don't show at all'!? Personally, I hate live preview. If the editor compiles while the document is mid-edit, it can easily result in errors and these can prevent re-compilation. Also, I generally like to think about content and compiling/formatting separately and live preview tends to feel intrusive. (It's also a resource hog. Or used to be.) Overleaf's works OK, but Kile's was nightmarish. Still, maybe it is better by now ;).